# How Add a Selection box to my website that looks like this

Tags: php, html

How to Add a Selection box to my website that looks like this .

[image]

or use an automatic search to add just like This website uses for tags . here ..

[image]

Thank you .

Comment: download selectize.js and follow the instructions

Comment: Thank you Sooo Much been searching for this for a while . Don't know what all the down votes are all about . thank you .

Comment: downvotes are most likely cause you didn't provide some code that proves you tried something. It kind of makes this question more of a "do it for me" kind of thing. I just happen to use selectize a lot and knew it was what you were looking for.

Comment: I'm using Wordpress so for me there isn't really any code involved just needed the name of the thing . sorry for the inconvenience and thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple JS plugins that do this. I use Chosen as it's quite flexible and allow for various other functionalities.